# How do I make a set from a sequence in clojure

Tags: clojure

What is an idiomatic way to convert a sequence to a set in Clojure? E.g what do I fill in at the dots?

```
(let s [1 1 2 2 3 3]
  ...)
```

So that it produces:

```
#{1 2 3}
```

I come up with:

```
(let [s [1 1 2 2 3 3]]
  (loop [r #{} s s]
    (if (empty? s) r (recur (conj r (first s)) (rest s)))))
```

But that seems not the way to go? Is there a function already that does this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

most collections have a function that produces them form anything seqable:

```
(set [1 1 2 2 3 3])
#{1 2 3}
```

for more interesting cases the `into` function is good to know about:

```
(into #{1}  [2 2 3 3])
#{1 2 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data Structures-Sets:

You can also get a set of the values in a collection using the set function:

```
(set [1 2 3 2 1 2 3])
#{1 2 3}
```